# How to add css to a form according to the user's role?

Tags: forms, theming

I know how to add css to individual form types using:

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'formtype_form':
      global $theme;
      $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
        drupal_get_path('theme', 'projectname') . '/css/new.css',
      );
    break;
 }
}
```

but how can I restrict this attached css to users with a single role?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$user` object and compare user role with current logged in user.

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user, $theme;

  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'formtype_form':
      // change user_role to whatever role you want to restrict this css
      if (in_array('user_role', array_values($user->roles))) {
        $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
          drupal_get_path('theme', 'projectname') . '/css/new.css',
        );
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the $theme global there but is not used?

Comment: @rooby $theme is useless with the current code, but maybe the questioner need it for a reason.